# On-Prem SQL server to ADLS Gen2 though ADF V2

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a pipeline which just copies data from On premise SQl Server database onto ADLS Gen2. It's very simple pipeline but I could see an error as in below but I don't have any parameter mentioned in accesskey in pipeline. :

### error message

Activity Copy Data1 failed: 'Type=System.ArgumentException,Message=The required property is not specified.
Parameter name: accountKey,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common,'

### When I use copy data approach I see following error.

The version "3.10.6838.1" of Self-hosted Integration Runtime "integrationRuntime1" is lower than 3.16.7033.3, which is not supported for your dataset. Please upgrade to the latest version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've upgraded self-hosted IR from 3.5 to 3.16. Now, am able to copy data from on premise sql server to adls gen2.